# Why do some employers withhold drug testing requirement until after interview?

Tags: interviewing, united-states, drug-test

I'm just trying to understand the reasoning behind why some employers would NOT tell you up front (if not in the online ad itself, at least early on in the process) that there is a drug testing requirement. I would think they'd have nothing to lose by people who don't want to take it giving up up front. Why would some of them tell you you need to do one AFTER you pass the interview process, much to a waste of everyone's time thus far? I'm really just trying to understand their reasoning process and not ranting.

My gut feeling is that it may be just a matter of poor communication on the part of the employer. Are there other reasons?

Comment: Not telling you is just poor communication.  Execute after you are hired can be part  privacy.  You can straight out ask if drug testing is required.

Comment: Me asking makes me sound like I'm doing drugs, which is something I'd rather not voluntarily disclose

Comment: Never heard of this drug test, before or after interview. Could you please add a country tag?

Comment: You are a software engineer?   Drug testing is pretty common in software.   You might want to go thru a recruiter that will look for jobs without drug testing.

Comment: @amphibient This depends on how you ask. You could be genuinely concerned about working in an atmosphere where there are drugs in the office, and legitimately want to know if drug testing is part of the screening process. If there *is* a drug test, there may be legal requirements that it be conducted fairly, so probing about this seems like fair game.

Comment: On the other hand, @JoeStrazzere, I don't know an employer that wouldn't notice that the candidate thought this was a question worth asking. Seriously, if you can't stay clean while job-hunting you've got a bigger problem than finding a job.

Comment: It's a matter of moral principle for me. I just don't find it appropriate to submit my bodily liquids, I have more self respect than that. OTOH, I've had lots of jobs that didn't require it and I correlate the coolness of a job with not demanding ridiculous drug tests

Comment: @Joe, they sure would answer if you asked explicitly. And then would most likely think you're asking cause you're an addict and reject you for "other reasons"

Comment: @amphibient: you've just said that the fact that they would ask is a deal-breaker for you. That being true, why do you care what they think? Ask, mutually rehect each other, move on to next possible position. If you're taking a stand, that requires accepting consequences of that stand... otherwise it's meaningless.

Comment: Because I wish they had asked before I had invested the time and effort into the interview process

Comment: Ok, lesson learned is that since this matters to you, _you_ have to be proactive and ask -- as for any other make-or0break item.

Comment: IMHO, i don't want colleagues that are addicts. I have one and it wasn't a pleasant experience. And if they aren't addicts then the answer is simple: quit using it!.

Comment: @magallanes Exactly. Drug use, bad credit and criminal history are all evidence of an underlying dysfunction that employers want to keep out of the workplace. That's why they screen. That's also why dysfunctional workplaces don't care if you use drugs.

Comment: @amphibient You clearly already know the answer to this question: companies quite understandably don't want dangerous, unstable drug users on their payroll. Letting people know before hand allows them to ease off for a few weeks or cheat. If you're angry you were "caught" by this, I strongly urge you to get the help you need immediately. Finding a job is not the priority for you--kicking your dangerous habit should be.

Comment: @A.McDaniel or its 95% of companies that do drug testing in the USA need to get over themselves pre employment drug screening should only be for safety or security ie security cleared jobs

Comment: @Neuromancer Wrong. No company should tolerate dangerous, unstable illegal drug users. Willingness to break laws is NOT compatable with employment in modern society (PS: "Legal" marijuana in your state is still a federal crime to use!)

Answer (score 11):

I work in the IT business in the USA. I smoke marijuana semi-regularly because it is the only thing that can consistently keep my shoulders from flaring up super bad.

Pretty much any major employer (Stream/Convergys, ACS, Xerox, Nike, Intel, most major ISPs, hospitals, etc...) have required drug tests. Out of the 15 or so job offers that I have received in this industry (out of the 6 jobs that I have held), only one company *did not* mandate a drug testing; and it was a startup. None of these mentioned drug testing any time before the on-boarding process.

I have found that simply asking the recruiter if the company drug tests goes a long way. If they ask why, I tell them that I have a rather busy schedule, and would need to ensure that I can block off the 1-4 hours it takes to do the test.

This isn't specific to this industry, though. My relatives who aren't so tech savvy are working minimum wage jobs around the area. From fast food joints to supermarkets to gas stations, it's expected that any new employer drug tests. Many of them do simple mouth swab tests, but expect a urine test anyways.

I would say that it isn't dishonest in the slightest, but this may be largely a cultural thing. The fact that such a large majority of employers require drug testing simply means that anyone looking to get a job in the USA should more or less expect the test and prepare for it. With proper preparation, they are not a problem. Finding out that your new employer *doesn't* test should be a relief or surprise, and not the expected norm here.

Answer (score 9):

As an employer, why would you tell them?

I don't want someone to stop for a few weeks to pass a test.

As a future employee I like this too.

I know I have less of a chance working with a habitual drug user and I know that people making hiring decisions have common sense about something.

Comment: Do you really think the surprise effect matters so much as to warrant wasting the whole interview efforts up to that point ? For example, the Home Depot has a very clear message to all applicants to not bother applying if they do drugs. I see your point, however it seems like it's based on some personal bias or inverted priorities

Comment: If they are a drug addict they won't be able to stop for a few weeks.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere If "habitual drug user" means they can stop for a few weeks then it would change the answer.

Comment: There are numerous ways in which criminal behavior by someone involved in the employer-employee relationship could be harmful. Generally, we don't invade people's privacy to force them to prove their innocence with no basis for suspicion. For example, I have a strong reluctance to work for a boss who is an embezzler or tax cheat. Should I  have the right to audit my potential manager's tax returns, bank statements etc. to establish their innocence before accepting a job?

Comment: If they interview and then send you to a drug test on a Monday, they will catch almost all casual drug users and all addicts, as it takes at least 48 hours for drugs to leave your system.

Comment: That's for heavy drugs. But pot stays in much longer in your organism than dangerous drugs. I really think this has nothing to do with job performance and all to do with breaking the person's self esteem

Comment: @amphibient - probably because HD doesn't want to pay for the drug tests, meaning they hire a lot more people than average company and a lot more people in the realm of doing drugs are applying.  Some of my answer is my opinion on things, but obviously a lot of companies agree with me.  For instance I have nothing against pot, but I have worked with some useless potheads.  While you may be an exception I have learned over the years of having many many potheads on my staff that they underperform on average.  Now I can remember 2-3 that were awesome employees - but talking averages.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - I begrudgingly made the answer more PC per your wonderful suggestion.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan - If there was a $30 test that provided that info it would be done.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I would certainly refuse to be drug tested. It is insulting and demeaning. So far, the issue has not come up, and I worked in the USA from 1975 to 2002.

Comment: This exactly. ESPECIALLY if I was working in a state where drugs were "legal" (read: still illegal by all measures that matter) like Colorado. I wouldn't dream of telling someone I drug tested, and I'd conduct random postemployment tests too. Maintaining a drug free workplace is obviously vitally important to the safety and security of my employees, I wouldn't take chances that someone could just ease off the dope for a few weeks then go right back to it.

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet to find out would be asking. We only can speculate.

At some Companys the drug test is not only at start date, but quite regularly. I would suspect that a different part of HR is responsible for the test. The ones hire you, the others manage you after you are in. This may just boil down to company processes and bad synchronization between departments.

For example at my previous company they stated in the job description "Driving license required". No one asked me about the license during interview. The interviewers have too much else in mind to care about such trivialities. I worked for one month in the company as they first approached me about my divers license. I had been driving the company cars before.

I would expect something similar with the drug test. If I hire a engineer or someone else with high education, I do not expect to find out later that he is a drug addict. The processes may still require me to check, but I would not see that as important (and therefore leave it for later).

Comment: I'm confused, you drove company cars but didn't have a license? Or you drove company cars but nobody actually checked that you have a license?

Comment: @stannius of course i have a license. Nobody checked or even asked. That story is really not important, just added it for color.

Comment: In the "oops, I don't have a license" case, the solution is usually to require the employee become licensed within N months (reassigned until they do, possibly at lower pay), or to negotiate that part of the contract, or both. This is not usually considered an acceptable approach for illegal drug use, not least because the company's insurance policies probably have that requirement and those are not easily negotiable.

Comment: @jwsc - Please explain the you think if a person has a joint at the weekend they are a drug addict.

Answer (score 3):

Drug testing is a normal requirement for being employed in the USA.  Not sure about other countries.  I'd hazard a guess that it's so common that most companies don't even consider that it needs to be stated.

I'd say it's right up there with background checks and NDAs.  Sure, it's poor communication, but, depending on where you live and what you do, you should expect to have to pass a test.

Comment: It is quite rare in Europe. I guess we take our privacy a bit more strongly that across the pond

Comment: I've never, ever had it here in Australia in a 20+ year career.

Comment: In the USA, it is not rare but definitely not common.  I suspect it is used to filter out applicants with normal self esteem who would probably object to being bullied.

Comment: @emory - Might be there to find employees who would work in such a job that "normal" employees could only endue if stoned

Comment: This would have been a good answer if it were posted in 1989.

Comment: What happened in 1989? Just curious

Comment: It's a USA thing for sure. Never encountered it in a white-collar job in Australia nor the UK, and like @JaneS that's in a 20+ year career. I believe it is not unknown for jobs involving e.g. heavy machinery.

Comment: 84% of US employers require drug testing, and those that do not skew heavily towards higher paying occupations.  Low skilled jobs at employers of more than maybe 10 people seem to almost universally require it.  http://www.drugfree.org/join-together/84-percent-of-employers-require-pre-employment-drug-tests/

Comment: @PaulBecotte I know that anecdotes are not data, but I have a very hard time believing those statistics.  If memory serves, I've had fourteen jobs between 1993 and today, three professional and the rest unskilled.  Of those, only two ever required drug testing: the Marine Corps and a charity that was partly funded by Federal grants.

Comment: It has never, ever happened to me anywhere in Europe. And if you asked me to do a drugs test, I would be so insulted that I'd tell you to stuff your job. On the other hand I've heard of lorry drives who figured out how a handful of poppy seeds can get you a few days of extra holidays...

Comment: @gnasher729, "if you asked me to do a drugs test, I would be so insulted that I'd tell you to stuff your job" - maybe that is why they wait until after you have given your current employer notice before telling you about the drug test

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I work in the US and that is not my experience.  I would want to be told early in the process.

Comment: Drug screens are not just a privacy issue. For example, suppose a drug screen reveals that you have marijuana in your system. Well, in many places usage of this substance is perfectly legal. And it may be used for medical reasons, which you should not be obliged to discuss with your employer. One should not expect to have to pass such a test without notification.

Comment: @EdHeal:  1989 was the peak of the "Just Say No" campaign spearheaded by American First Lady Nancy Reagan and the middle of a big ramp-up of drug testing by employers.  I question how "normal" it actually is, because it sure doesn't seem that way in professional circles.  The last time I was asked to do one was 1991.

Comment: War on drugs - seems to last forever. Remind me who are winning

Comment: @EdHeal: the lawyers.

Comment: @EdHeal - It seems we can't find Noel or Daniel Webster to sign the surrender papers.  This sort of thing happens when you declare wars on nouns.

Comment: Been in the US workforce since 1990.  Never, not even once, had a job that required drug screening.

Comment: @PoleHoleSet: that's nice.  Roughly half of people have been drug screened in the USA and the numbers are increasing. 
 http://www.slate.com/articles/health_and_science/cover_story/2015/12/workplace_drug_testing_is_widespread_but_ineffective.html

Comment: The only way to stop this is for Americans to start standing up for their own privacy and liberty. As a non-American, I see a weird tendency for Americans to only claim rights and liberties that are protected by their constitution, and permit any invasion of privacy the constitution permits.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: Americans absolutely have the right to not submit to a drug test.  Just like the owners / managers of those companies have the right not to hire someone that refuses.  Alternatively, you also have a right to start your own company and implement your own rules.  This isn't an issue of liberty or personal rights.

Comment: @NotMe I agree that Americans have the right to refuse drug tests. The problem is that they don't assert their rights unless they are protected by the US constitution.

Comment: Incidentally, @NotMe's assertion that employer drug tests are not an issue of liberty or personal rights is a perfect illustration of the amazing tolerance for unreasonable searches, invasions of privacy, and presumption of guilt that Americans have when the offender is a business.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put... Believe it or not... Some people cheat.

If the drug test is disclosed up front it gives people who are going to cheat an opportunity to do so. As mentioned in another answer, some people will just clean up for a few weeks before the test in order to pass. Others will try to use one of the never ending commercially available products to try to beat the test.

Like it or not, it's a reality and a financial reality too. Sending people to a lab for testing isn't cheap, but employers often get discounts on insurance for doing so.

They also do this to limit their liability. If you're ever injured on the job you can expect to be tested. If you fail, you'll lose your benefits and most likely your job as well.

Answer (score 1):

> reasoning behind why some employers would NOT tell you up front

Nothing malicious about it, they forgot about it, it's an industry where it's mandatory or they just didn't deem it important or expect drug users to be applying.

Comment: It's a huge and inappropriate assumption to make in 2016

Comment: @amphibient if you don't smoke anything that makes you paranoid it isn't. You think it's a new way of doing undercover Vice Squad stings?

Comment: @Kilisi if it is industry mandatory then candidates probably should know about it before hand whether or not they are told.  If it is not industry mandatory, then it kills about half a day (uncompensated) - which is important.  If drug users are not expected to apply, then why test for drugs?

Comment: @amphibient Drug testing is not an assumption of drug use, but a verification of non-use. People lie, even in 2016 (whatever that's supposed to mean).

Comment: @emory  *"it kills about half a day"* A simple urinalysis takes about 15 minutes. An oral swab takes less. You go in, provide a specimen (pee in a cup), sign a form, then leave. *"(uncompensated)"* Drug tests *are* compensated in that the company covers the cost on your behalf. *"If drug users are not expected to apply, then why test for drugs?"* Because people lie.

Comment: @Substantial If it takes you 15 minutes to urinate, then you should probably see a doctor.  Regardless, time to pee is just a small part of the time cost and you were going to pee anyway so it probably should not be counted at all.  I had to do a drug test a couple of years back.  The chosen lab was in another city.  I had to take a bus and a couple of transfers to get there.  Bus fare was on me.  No one offered to pay for my time.  What if instead, a drug test worker came to my house to collect my urine?

Comment: @emory You clearly misunderstood what I said regarding 15 minutes. The test doesn't take half a day. Now, if the journey takes half a day, **that's your problem**, no the employer's, not the drug tester's. Drug testing is part of the application process. You don't get paid for applying to a job. That's ridiculous. Transporting yourself is **ALWAYS** your responsibility at your expense.

Comment: @Substantial it is immaterial whether transportation is my responsibility or my employer's responsibility.  It is a problem that I will deal with one way or the other.  If I want/need your job, I will bite the bullet and go - while resenting you for wasting my time and money.  If I don't want/need the job, I can simply decline to proceed with the application.  It is not my problem, if you can't fill a position b/c people are dropping out mid-application.